# Mintest Rails4: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR: null value in column "name" violates not-null constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, factory-bot, minitest

I'm trying test my rails 4 application with MiniTest. I've some seed data, to get app setup. Once seed data is loaded in test database, I try to run test.

test_seed.rake

```
namespace :db do
  namespace :test do
    desc "Load seed data before running tests"
    task :prepare => :environment do
      puts "\nLoading Seed data.....\n\n"
      Rake::Task["db:seed"].invoke
      puts "\n....Seed data loaded!\n\n"
    end
  end
end
```

Having done that, I do

```
rake db:test:prepare
```

Then when I simply put 'rake' command(as of now I do not have any testcase written)

test_helper.rb

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require "rails/test_help"
require "minitest/rails"

# To add Capybara feature tests add `gem "minitest-rails-capybara"`
# to the test group in the Gemfile and uncomment the following:
require "minitest/rails/capybara"

# Uncomment for awesome colorful output
require "minitest/pride"

# Code coverage, refer https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start

# Create customizable MiniTest output formats
require "minitest/reporters"
Minitest::Reporters.use!(
    Minitest::Reporters::SpecReporter.new,
    ENV,
    Minitest.backtrace_filter
)

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending!
  include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.(yml|csv) for all tests in alphabetical order.
  #
  # Note: You'll currently still have to declare fixtures explicitly in integration tests
  # -- they do not yet inherit this setting
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
  extend MiniTest::Spec::DSL
end

class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  extend MiniTest::Spec::DSL
  include Capybara::DSL
end
```

Gemfile:

```
group :test do
  # MiniTest
  gem 'minitest-spec-rails', '5.2.0'
  gem 'minitest-rails-capybara', '2.1.1'
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'guard-minitest', '2.3.1'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', "~> 4.2.1"
  gem 'faker', '1.4.3'
  gem 'simplecov', '0.9.2', require: false
end
```

Existing test, role_test.rb:

```
require 'test_helper'

class RoleTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase


  test "nothing" do
    assert true
    # role_names = Role.where(name: 'superAdmin').collect(&:name)
    # assert_includes role_names, 'SuperAdmin', 'it should include role superAdmin'
  end
```

It fails with following error:

```
RoleTest
  test_0001_nothing                                              ERROR (0.02s)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:         ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "name" violates not-null constraint
        DETAIL:  Failing row contains (980190962, null, 2015-03-31 19:51:59, 2015-03-31 19:51:59, null, null, null, null, null, null, null).
        : INSERT INTO "companies" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2015-03-31 19:51:59', '2015-03-31 19:51:59', 980190962)



Fabulous run in 0.05302s
1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Can anyone help me on this, why at all I'm getting this error? And if possible, suggestion to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: The error is coming from `test/fixtures/companies.yml` file. Seeding the database does not affect the test run..

Comment: Thanks. Yea, companies.yml was blank.